# Cannot install debug.log file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with npm

```
2018-07-03T06:26:50.490789+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs slacky- 
slack
2018-07-03T06:26:50.491029+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't 
available, you can get their info via:
2018-07-03T06:26:50.491259+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
slacky-slack
2018-07-03T06:26:50.491483+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely 
additional logging output above.
2018-07-03T06:26:50.504304+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-07-03T06:26:50.504649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the 
following file with any support request:
2018-07-03T06:26:50.504652+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2018-07-03T06:26:50.562975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-07-03T06:26:50.591872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to 
crashed
2018-07-03T06:27:22.933639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=POST path="/v1/account/register" 
host=chattychatj.herokuapp.com request_id=e647073e-4b59-4ca4-a2a0- 
c6b17a3b610e fwd="49.34.114.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=httpsstrong text
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: please tell me how to solve it

Comment: You have done something wrong with the slack API

Comment: Follow the error message `npm owner ls 
slacky-slack`

Comment: What's the command you ran?